# Getting ORA error when selecting external table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create external table , but I am getting error .

Here is the code using to create external table,

```
CREATE TABLE "emp_ext"
(
  "EMPNO" NUMBER(6),
  "ENAME" VARCHAR2(20),
  "JOB" VARCHAR2(25),
  "MGR" NUMBER(6),
  "HIRE_DATE" DATE,
  "SAL" NUMBER(8,2),
  "COMM" NUMBER(2,2),
  "DEPTNO" NUMBER(4)
)
ORGANIZATION external
(
  TYPE oracle_loader
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY EXTDIR
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
(
  RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE CHARACTERSET US7ASCII
  BADFILE 'EXTDIR':'employees.bad'
  LOGFILE 'employees.log_xt'
  READSIZE 1048576
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LDRTRIM
  REJECT ROWS WITH ALL NULL FIELDS
  (
   "EMPLOYEE_ID" CHAR(255)
    TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
    "ENAME" CHAR(255)
    TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
    "JOB" CHAR(255)
    TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
    "HIRE_DATE" CHAR(255)
     TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
    "SAL" CHAR(255)
     TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
    "COMM" CHAR(255)
     TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"',
    "DEPTNO" CHAR(255)
     TERMINATED BY "," OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  )
)
  location
  (
   'datafile.txt'
  )
)
```

I have READ/WRITE permissions to the external directory.

Table has been created. When I try to do select * from "emp_ext" , I'm getting below error

```
SQL> select * from "emp_ext";
select * from "emp_ext"
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-04043: table column not found in external source: EMPNO
ORA-06512: at "SYS.ORACLE_LOADER", line 19
```

Comment: Error message looks pretty clear, no?  Where is a sample of this datefile.txt ?  You have EMPNO in table definition, but  EMPLOYEE_ID in row/column definition for file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first field specified in the `CREATE TABLE` is `EMPNO`, but the first field specified in the record definition is `EMPLOYEE_ID`. These must match. Pick one or the other.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should change

```
   "EMPLOYEE_ID" CHAR(255)
```

for

```
"EMPNO" CHAR(255)
```

Where is MGR data comming from?

Comment: @SathishKumar You're welcome. Mark the question as answered.